# After running docker-compose, port on Amazon EC2 are not getting mapped to the public IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I created a swarm on AWS by running

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --amazonec2-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --amazonec2-vpc-id $AWS_VPC_ID --amazonec2-region "us-west-2" --engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8 aws-mh-keystore
eval "$(docker-machine env aws-mh-keystore)"

docker run -d -p "8500:8500" -h "consul"  progrium/consul -server -bootstrap

docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --amazonec2-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --amazonec2-vpc-id $AWS_VPC_ID --amazonec2-region "us-west-2" --engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8 --engine-label n_type=master   --swarm --swarm-master --swarm-strategy "spread" --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip aws-mh-keystore):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip aws-mh-keystore):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth0:2376" aws-swarm-master

eval $(docker-machine env --swarm aws-swarm-master)
```

And I created two nodes using the following command

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --amazonec2-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --amazonec2-vpc-id $AWS_VPC_ID --amazonec2-region "us-west-2" --engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8 --engine-label n_type=worker --swarm --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip aws-mh-keystore):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip aws-mh-keystore):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth0:2376"  aws-swarm-node-01

docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-access-key $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --amazonec2-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --amazonec2-vpc-id $AWS_VPC_ID --amazonec2-region "us-west-2" --engine-opt dns=8.8.8.8 --engine-label n_type=worker --swarm --swarm-discovery="consul://$(docker-machine ip aws-mh-keystore):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$(docker-machine ip aws-mh-keystore):8500" --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth0:2376"  aws-swarm-node-02
```

After that I use the following command to build my multi-container app using:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

At this stage, the build process completes successfully and everything seems fine.

However, when I run

```
docker-compose ps
```

I see that the exposed ports are 0.0.0.0:<> -> tcp:<>
The ideal behavior should involve a port mapping from the container to the EC2 host.

My docker-compose file is as follows

```
version: "2"
services: 
  web_api:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      # args: ["constraint:engine.labels.n_type==master"]
    hostname: web_api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    links: 
      - worker
    depends_on: 
      - worker
 # Redis
   redis:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-redis
    # image: redis
    hostname: redis
    ports:
       - "6379:6379"

 # Celery worker
 worker:
     build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-celery
      # args: ["constraint:engine.labels.n_type==worker"]
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
    # environment:
      # - "constraint:engine.labels.n_type == worker"
    command: ./run_celery.sh
```

Why is the AWS port mapping not being assigned? 
I have established the correct inbound rules for the security group being used.

Comment: Would you please post the output of docker-compose ps?

Comment: Also post the output of sudo netstat -ntlp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that I had not allowed ICMP communications in my security group configuration. For some reason, that was causing my problems. Once I configured the inbound rules for ICMP in my security group correctly, I was able to access my docker containers.